# Picker values are repeating in textfields for all rows in section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uipickerview

[image]

I am using pickers for 2 textfields in custom cell. While selecting picker value for one field, it repeates for all rows in one section.I am using following code. I am setting picker for action of custom button for that textfield.

```
int pickerMoved=0;

-(IBAction)genderpickerbtnpressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"genderpickerbtnpressed called ");
    UIActionSheet *asheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select your gender"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                               otherButtonTitles:@"Select", nil];

    [asheet setTag:200];

    UIPickerView *statePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
    statePicker.delegate=self;

    statePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [statePicker setTag:11];
    [asheet addSubview:statePicker];
    [asheet showInView:[self.view superview]];
    [asheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 700)];
    [asheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 383)];
}



- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) {

        if(actionSheet.tag==200) {

            if(buttonIndex==0) {

                if(pickerMoved>0) {
                    NSLog(@"selected item is %d",pickerMoved);
                    NSLog(@"selected data is %@",[self.genderarray objectAtIndex:pickerMoved] );

                    self.savingsStr=[self.genderarray objectAtIndex:pickerMoved];
                } else {

                    NSLog(@"distanceArray object at index %@",[self.genderarray objectAtIndex:0]);
                    self.savingsStr=[self.genderarray objectAtIndex:0];
                }

            }
        }
        pickerMoved=0;
        [self.tripView reloadData];
    }



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTripViewCell *cell = (MyTripViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"acell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTripViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        cell=Tblcell;
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {

        Passenger *temp = [appDelegate.ADULTS objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@"adults array count is %d",[appDelegate.ADULTS count]);
        cell.textfield.text = temp.name;

        cell.gendertextfield.text = self.savingsStr;
        cell.dobtextfield.text =self.datepickerstr;
        cell.gendertextfield.tag=indexPath.row;

        [savingsStr release];
        NSLog(@"temp.gender is ----- %@",temp.gender);

    }
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Values are repeating for gender textfields in adults section. How to copy picker value to cell. Any idea share with me.Thanks.

Comment: can u tell me after selecting from picker tableview is shown..? or first tableview is shown with empty field, then taping the field u r showing picker & filling the text fields..?

Comment: first table view is shown with empty fields then give name and select pickers for gender and DOB .now problem is gender and DOB values are repeating for all adults section.how to set tag for textfield

Comment: Just now noticed that, in the above code you are missing one closing bracket in the method. - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex. Please add it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `cellForRow` method you have

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
```

i think it should be

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)
```

so that it fills only for first row, and also you need to use both conditions if you want to fill for first row of first section.

Comment: no it is if(indexpath.section == 0) because it has 3 sections ie. adults details, child and infants details

Comment: in adult field we want name textfield,gender textfield,and DOB textfield and so on for remaining sections. Now i want how to set the tag for each text field .it didn't have predifined no. of rows because we give in previous view.ie no. of adults,no of child,no of infants

Comment: but i don't have predefined no of rows to set if(indexPath.row)

Comment: so how can i set tag for rows

Comment: directly u can set using `textField.tag = indexPath.row;` in `cellForRow` method.. can u tell me hw many sections u hav, hw many texFields? in each row, can u give me screenshot?

Comment: how can i send screenshot in comments?

Comment: uplaoded, no.of rows in adults,child,infants are defined in previous view and we can increment rows by clicking add adults,add child,add infants to respective sections.

Comment: ok.. i got it now.. the best thing we can do is ur tag should hav both section & row, from which u can come to know, which field is it.. then maintain this selected indexPath globally, so that after value is picked from picker, u can set to the right field..